# ng-model table show data angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I ma very beginner in Angularjs and pardon my silly mistakes. I have a table which shows data in three columns and i want to filter this table based on a condition and hide unnecessary data in one column which contains integers. I have used ng-show with some condition linked to ng-model  and this is working perfect if i enter data in my ng-model only after loading total form. But, i want to show all the table data in the beginning and then hide unnecessary data based on ng-show condition.

How can i do this? I am struggling!

```
<tr ng-show= "change > val1 " ng-repeat="change in montlyProjection();"  >
          <td>some data</td>
          <td class="number">some data</td>
          <td class="number" ng-class="positiveNegative(convertToNumber(startBalance) + change)">some data</td>
        </tr>

</strong><input type="text" ng-model="val1" placeholder="Enter Amount" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<tr ng-show="((change > val1) || !val1)" ng-repeat="change in monthlyProjection()">
```

Try adding additional conditions to the ng-show directive.  If !val doesn't work try using "angular.equals(val1,'')" or "angular.isDefined(val1)"